# How to make a specific link nofollow in BBCode?

Tags: bbcode, phpbb, nofollow

How to make a specific link nofollow in BBCode. I am a new user of PHPBB, and in which while posting content, I tried to make links nofollow in BBCode but its not working. How to do it?

[url=https://google.com]google[/url]

This is the code, now how to make it nofollow. I tried [urlnf] tag as well but didn't work out.

Comment: Are you an admin on the desired phpBB board?

Comment: Hello Ramen, 

Its my own newly built forum

However, I have used adding custom new BBCode, and implemented it well already today morning.
Now problem is fixed, and I posted about it too.. that you can see here => https://24x7forum.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=26